# How to delete object with a mouse click?

Tags: java

I made a simple FlowChat Editor that creates rectangles and triangles and connects them to each other and shows the way from up to down. I can move this elements on screen too.

I am now trying to create a button to delete the element which I clicked. There is problem that I can delete `MyTriangle` objects, but I can't delete `MyRectangle` objects. It deletes but not object which I clicked. I delete from first object to last.

Here is my code:

```
 if (deleteObj) {

        if (rectsList.size() != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < rectsList.size(); i++) {
                MyRect rect = (MyRect) rectsList.get(i);
                if (e.getX() <= rect.c.x + 50 && e.getX() >= rect.c.x - 50
 && e.getY() <= rect.c.y + 15 && e.getY() >= rect.c.y - 15) {
                    rectsList.remove(rect);
                    System.out.println("This is REctangle DELETED\n");

                }

            }
        }
        if (triangleList.size() != 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < triangleList.size(); j++) {
                MyTriangle trian = (MyTriangle) triangleList.get(j);

                if (e.getX() <= trian.c.x + 20 && e.getX() >= trian.c.x - 20 
&& e.getY() <= trian.c.y + 20 && e.getY() >= trian.c.y - 20) {
                    triangleList.remove(trian);
                    System.out.println("This is Triangle  Deleted\n");

                }

            }
        }
```

**Edit**  Here MyRectangle and MyTriangle classes

```
public class MyRect extends Ellipse2D.Double {

Point c;
Point in;
Point out;
int posX;
int posY;
int width = 100;
int height = 30;
  int count;


public MyRect(Point center, Point input, Point output,int counter) {

    c = center;
    in = input;
    out = output;
    count=counter;

}

void drawMe(Graphics g) {
    //    in.x=c.x+20;
    int posX = c.x;
    int posY = c.y;
    int posInX = in.x;
    int posInY = in.y;
    int posOutX = out.x;
    int posOutY = out.y;




    g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    g.drawString(" S "+count ,posX-5, posY+5);


    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawRect(posX-50, posY-15, width, height);
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.drawRect(posInX-3, posInY-9, 6, 6);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.drawRect(posOutX-3, posOutY+3, 6, 6);


}
}

public class MyTriangle {

Point c;
Point in ;
Point outYES ;
Point outNO ;
int posX;
int posY;
int count;

public MyTriangle(Point center,Point input,Point outputYES,Point outputNO,int counter)     {

    c = center;
    in = input;
    outYES = outputYES;
    outNO = outputNO;
    count=counter;
}

void drawMe(Graphics g) {

    int posX = c.x;
    int posY = c.y;
    int posInX=in.x;
    int posInY=in.y;
    int posOutYESX=outYES.x;
    int posOutYESY=outYES.y;
    int posOutNOX=outNO.x;
    int posOutNOY=outNO.y;

    int[] xPoints = {posX - 50, posX, posX + 50, posX};
    int[] yPoints = {posY, posY - 30, posY, posY + 30};

     g.setColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    g.drawString(" T "+count,posX-5, posY+5);
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, 4);
   // draw input
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.drawRect(posInX-3,posInY-9, 6, 6);
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.drawRect(posOutYESX-9,posOutYESY-3 , 6, 6);
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.drawRect(posOutNOX-3,posOutNOY+3 , 6, 6);
}
}
```

**Edit 2**

Here my funcs to add object to list.Is there could be ant mistake?Because I am her ceratıng new object of that calss and  I am addıng that object to rectlist or trianglelist..

```
    public void initRect(Point c, Point in, Point out) {
    sCounter++;
    MyRect myrects = new MyRect(c, in, out, sCounter);

    rectsList.add(myrects);
    s_And_t_List.add(myrects);

    objectCounter.add("S " + sCounter);

    selectablePanel.repaint();
}

public void initTriangle(Point c, Point in, Point outYES, Point outNO) {
    tCounter++;
    MyTriangle mytriangles = new MyTriangle(c, in, outYES, outNO, tCounter);

    triangleList.add(mytriangles);
    s_And_t_List.add(mytriangles);
    objectCounter.add("T " + tCounter);
    selectablePanel.repaint();
}
```

Comment: Is (`rect.c.x`, `rect.c.y`) the center of the rectangle, or the top left corner?

Comment: it is center.It is where the mouse clicked and it draws racte as a center point.

Comment: post the MyRect and MyTriangle classes

Comment: Java's Path2D, Polygon and similar classes are designed to do these sort of point-containment checks or intersection checks for you. Have you looked at those?

Comment: Yes.My classes also uses them.My problem i can delete triangle wwhere i clicked but  if  I have more than one rect object if i click 5th or 9th it deletes 1th then if i click secon time 2th...I know that  I can catch exact object because i can drag and drop it.

Comment: Before you remove the object from your list, print out the x,y coordinate of the mouse and the x,y coordinate of your rectangles starting point.  It seems like you logic must not be working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your logic is wrong.  In your Rectangle class why not make a method returning a boolean that tests if a given set of coordinates is contained in your object.  For example:

```
public boolean contains(int x, int y){  
    if(x_starting_point <= x && x <= x_starting_point+width
    && y_starting_point <= y && y <= y_starting_point+height)
        return true; 

    return false;
}
```

Comment: is this for checking am i found object?but my codes work too.It can found exact object

Comment: I'm assuming that `rect.c.x` means the center of his rectangle, so it makes sense that he's subtracting and adding half of the width to get the extents I guess...

Comment: yes.. I thinf   rect.c.x-50<clickX<rect.c.x+50 and rect.c.y-15<clickY<rect.c.y+15  here clickX and clickY will be in   rectangle and I think it is enough to find that object.Am I right?

Comment: Yes this was to check if you are finding the correct rectangle to remove.  It seems that there must either be something wrong with your logic to find the rectangle to remove, or with your logic to remove the object.  I was thinking it was the logic to find the object since you seem to always delete the first element in your list.  One thing you could try is to print out the position in your list of the element that you are deleting and print out the position in your list that your rectangle is in to make sure they are the same.

Comment: I prınted coordinates where mouse clicked and coordınates of deleted object and they are the same ....

Comment: try printing the coordinates of all the objects in you list when you go to delete them.  This is to make sure all of the coordinates are different.